# How to apply several functions on each data frame in a list of data frames in R?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have 19 different files for 19 different species that all contain the same columns in one folder.  I upload them all into R in a list using:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)

length(myfiles)

[1] 19
```

What I need to do is conduct a couple of functions on each of the data frames in the list, create new new files and export those, for example:

```
data <- myfiles[[1]]

data1 <- subset(data, B==1)
data2 <- subset(data, B==2)

mean1 <- mean(data1$Y)
mean2 <- mean(data2$Y)

means <-rbind(mean1, mean2)

write.csv(means, "means1.csv")
```

I want to apply the codea aboe to each of the data frames in `myfiles` but am not sure is it better to use `for loop` or `lapply` and how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to create a separate file name for each result, you should `lapply` over the indices `i` from 1 to 19.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)

i = 1:length(myfiles)

fn <- function(i) {
  data = myfiles[[i]]
  data1 <- subset(data, B==1)
  data2 <- subset(data, B==2)
  
  mean1 <- mean(data1$Y)
  mean2 <- mean(data2$Y)
  
  means <-rbind(mean1, mean2)
  
  write.csv(means, paste0("means", i ".csv"))
}

lapply(i, fn)
```

Comment: This worked great you just missed the clossing bracket at ```write.csv(means, paste0("means", i ".csv"))```

Comment: Btw, how would you edit the code to write the files in another folder, not in the set working directory? I tried with ```fileName <- paste(datapath, paste0("means", i, ".csv"), sep ="\\") write.csv(means, fileName)``` but it does not seem to work, it runs to code fine and in the console I see it but it does not create the files for some reason.

Comment: @starski maybe check again? it works for me when I use relative and absolute pathname

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.

```r
# make up reproducible data
set.seed(2023)
myfiles <- replicate(3, data.frame(B = 1:3, Y = rnorm(12)), simplify = FALSE)

# these are the output filenames, all created at once
outfiles <- paste0("means", seq_along(myfiles), ".csv")

# the 'aggregate' formula is the same for all files
Map(\(x, out) {
  agg <- aggregate(Y ~ B, x, mean)
  write.csv(agg, out)
}, myfiles, outfiles)
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>